# SQL: grouping to have exact rows

Tags: sqlite

Let's say there is a schema:

```
|date|value|
```

DBMS is SQLite.

I want to get N groups and calculate AVG(value) for each of them.

Sample:

```
2020-01-01 10:00|2.0
2020-01-01 11:00|2.0
2020-01-01 12:00|3.0
2020-01-01 13:00|10.0
2020-01-01 14:00|2.0
2020-01-01 15:00|3.0
2020-01-01 16:00|11.0
2020-01-01 17:00|2.0
2020-01-01 18:00|3.0
```

Result (N=3):

```
2020-01-01 11:00|7.0/3
2020-01-01 14:00|15.0/3
2020-01-01 17:00|16.0/3
```

I need to use a windowing function, like NTILE, but it seems NTILE is not usable after GROUP BY. It can create buckets, but then how can I use these buckets for aggregation?

```
SELECT
   /*AVG(*/value/*)*/,
   NTILE (3) OVER (ORDER BY date) bucket
FROM
   test
/*GROUP BY bucket*/
/*GROUP BY NTILE (3) OVER (ORDER BY date) bucket*/
```

Also dropped the test data and this query into [DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5zfyquviGnxzrwKJtL9crx/2).

Comment: No, there is no way in SQL language to adjust the `GROUP BY` expression accordingly.

Comment: Is it also not possible to get an average for every N number of rows? I.e get the avg of every 5 rows from the table?

Comment: Edit your question with sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: Also there is no date_format() function in SQLite. How does your code work?

Comment: @forpas: I used strftime, but now I rephrased the question, as it seem there is no need for grouping by date if I can utilize windowing functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NTILE()` window function to create the groups and aggregate:

```
SELECT 
  DATETIME(MIN(DATE), ((STRFTIME('%s', MAX(DATE)) - STRFTIME('%s', MIN(DATE))) / 2) || ' second') date, 
  ROUND(AVG(value), 2) avg_value
FROM (
  SELECT *, NTILE(3) OVER (ORDER BY date) grp
  FROM test
) 
GROUP BY grp;
```

To change the number of rows in each bucket, you must change the number 3 inside the parentheses of `NTILE()`.

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aygpYpfPCLY51u8voRABhH/5).
Results:

```
| date                | avg_value |
| ------------------- | --------- |
| 2020-01-01 11:00:00 | 2.33      |
| 2020-01-01 14:00:00 | 5         |
| 2020-01-01 17:00:00 | 5.33      |
```

Comment: Actually I think I always need to use 2 instead of `(3-1)`, that's the average of max-min dates.

Comment: @Daniel fine but there is 1 problem. For this case the number 3 is divides the rows in 3 groups each containing 3 rows. Your requirement is every N rows. So NTILE will nit work in any case. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @Daniel I edited. The use of NTILE is wrong in your case because NTILE(N) divides the rows of the table in N groups, not necessarily containing N rows in each group. The correct way is with ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: Wait, I think we are not on the same path now: NTILE is working beautifully, I need N groups. But calculating the average date (first column) seems wrong, I think it should be `DATETIME(MIN(DATE), ((STRFTIME('%s', MAX(DATE)) - STRFTIME('%s', MIN(DATE))) / 2) || ' second')`.

Comment: If you need N groups then my previous code would work. But in your question you say * for every N rows*. Which is correct?

Comment: For the sample data you posted, both requirements are actually the same because there are 3 groups each containing 3 rows. But if there are 30 rows do you still need 3 groups each containing 10 rows?

Comment: For the calculation of the average time you are right. I edited.

Comment: One more thing: performance-wise, what do you think, this is faster, or grouping by `(id - 1) / (((SELECT Count(*) FROM table) + 2) / 3)` ?

Comment: `grp` is calculated inside the subquery and ready to use for aggregation. Why would you use such a complex expression? I'm not even sure if the optimizer would calculate the subquery  `(SELECT Count(*) FROM table)` only once.

Comment: Based on my test, with around 100.000 records, NTILE calculates for 1.5s, and this subquery group for 0.5s. Multiple tests, bucket size 50. Test table has ID for Primary key. I'm confused, really thought NTILE will be faster. Did another tests with 10 as bucket size, same result. 1s advantage for subquery group :(

Comment: If these are the correct timings then there is no question about which one to use. It seems hard to grasp though that a window function performs worse.

Comment: One more thing. Using the id to create the groups is not a good idea. After insertions and deletions there may be gaps between the ids, or missing ids may be reused for newer dates.

Comment: Yes, group by id seems wrong indeed. I found out that adding row number instead of ntile, and then group by `(id-1)/((total+bucketsize-1)/bucketsize)` produces the same result as ntile, but is somewhat 40% faster.

Comment: If you have defined id as `integer primary key` then id is just an alias of `rowid` (https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html). So you can't depend on rowid either if there are gaps. You may get groups with uneven number of rows.

Comment: I meant `row_number()` window function. Based on my trials, if I have gaps in `id`, the grouping will give wrong sized buckets. But if on the same data I use `row_number()` it will result perfectly equal buckets in spite of the gaps.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to use a windowing function, like NTILE, but it seems NTILE is not usable after GROUP BY. It can create buckets, but then how can I use these buckets for aggregation?

You first use `NTILE` to assign bucket numbers in a subquery, then group by it in an outer query.

*Using sub-query*

```sql
SELECT bucket
     , AVG(value) AS avg_value
  FROM ( SELECT value
              , NTILE(3) OVER ( ORDER BY date ) AS bucket
           FROM test
       ) x
 GROUP BY bucket
 ORDER BY bucket
```

*Using `WITH` clause*

```sql
WITH x AS (
   SELECT date
        , value
        , NTILE(3) OVER ( ORDER BY date ) AS bucket
     FROM test
)
SELECT bucket
     , COUNT(*) AS bucket_size
     , MIN(date) AS from_date
     , MAX(date) AS to_date
     , MIN(value) AS min_value
     , AVG(value) AS avg_value
     , MAX(value) AS max_value
     , SUM(value) AS sum_value
  FROM x
 GROUP BY bucket
 ORDER BY bucket
```