# SQLite: create equal date ranges and query data based on them?

Tags: sqlite, common-table-expression

I have datas in a table with schema:

```
Id INTEGER,
date DATETIME,
value REAL
```

id is primary key, and I have an index on date column to speed up querying values within a specific date range.

What should I do if I need N equal date ranges between specific start and end dates, and query aggregated datas for each date range?

For example:

- Start date: 2015-01-01
- End date: 2019-12-31
- N: 5

In this case equal date intervals should be:

- 2015-01-01 ~ 2015-12-31
- 2016-01-01 ~ 2016-12-31
- 2017-01-01 ~ 2017-12-31
- 2018-01-01 ~ 2018-12-31
- 2019-01-01 ~ 2019-12-31

And the query should aggregate all values (AVG) in between those intervals, so I would like to have 5 total rows after the execution.

Maybe something with CTE?

Comment: Didn't your [earlier question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62833358/sql-grouping-to-have-exact-rows) have a usable answer?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Because let's imagine I have 200 datas from 2019-01-01 to 2019-12-31. Data collection in january was more frequent, so I have 100 rows in january and other 100 rows for the rest. Buckets will be created (N=10) with size of 20. So if you visualize it on chart, date as X-axis will distort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do it.
They both use recursive ctes but return different results.

The 1st one with `NTILE()`:

```
with 
  dates as (select '2015-01-01' mindate, '2019-12-31' maxdate),
  alldates as (
    select mindate date from dates
    union all
    select date(a.date, '1 day') 
    from alldates a cross join dates d
    where a.date < d.maxdate
  ),
  groups as (
    select *, ntile(5) over (order by date) grp
    from alldates
  ),
  cte as (
    select min(date) date1, max(date) date2
    from groups
    group by grp
  )
select * from cte;
```

Results:

```
| date1      | date2      |
| ---------- | ---------- |
| 2015-01-01 | 2016-01-01 |
| 2016-01-02 | 2016-12-31 |
| 2017-01-01 | 2017-12-31 |
| 2018-01-01 | 2018-12-31 |
| 2019-01-01 | 2019-12-31 |
```

And the 2nd builds the groups with math:

```
with 
  dates as (select '2015-01-01' mindate, '2019-12-31' maxdate),
  cte1 as (
    select mindate date from dates
    union all
    select date(
      c.date, 
      ((strftime('%s', d.maxdate) - strftime('%s', d.mindate)) / 5) || ' second'
    )
    from cte1 c inner join dates d
    on c.date < d.maxdate
  ),
  cte2 as (
    select date date1, lead(date) over (order by date) date2
    from cte1
  ),
  cte as (
    select date1, 
      case 
        when date2 = (select maxdate from dates) then date2
        else date(date2, '-1 day')
      end date2
    from cte2
    where date2 is not null
  )  
select * from cte
```

Results:

```
| date1      | date2      |
| ---------- | ---------- |
| 2015-01-01 | 2015-12-31 |
| 2016-01-01 | 2016-12-30 |
| 2016-12-31 | 2017-12-30 |
| 2017-12-31 | 2018-12-30 |
| 2018-12-31 | 2019-12-31 |
```

In both cases you can get the averages by joining the table to the cte:

```
select c.date1, c.date2, avg(t.value) avg_value 
from cte c inner join tablename t
on t.date between c.date1 and c.date2
group by c.date1, c.date2
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems suitable. I did something similar, but can not get the performance below 500ms. I changed the dates to integer, which decreases greatly the execution time, but still around 6-700ms. Base table has ~700k rows. Date has index. Do you think 700k rows shall do this in 6-700ms? i7 desktop, tons of RAM, newest SQLite, built with O3.

Comment: SQLite is not the most suitable rdbms for these cases. Although 700k rows is not that huge amount of data you can't expect much better results. You can experiment by trying different ways of doing this. For example the 1st query I posted first constructs a resultset of 5x365 rows in order to split it in 5 groups while the 2nd uses math operations to create the groups which must be far more performant. But in the end both queries must be joined to the table of 700k rows. One more thing: try instead of BETWEEN to use: `on t.date >= c.date1 and t.date <= c.date2`.